# APRS-IS filter by message sender

Tags: digital-modes, aprs

I'm using [KD0NKS' JS-based APRS-IS demo](https://github.com/KD0NKS/aprs-is-demo) to query APRS-IS servers directly. I'm trying to only receive **messages sent from my callsign** using [server-side filters](https://www.aprs-is.net/javAPRSFilter.aspx).

I've tried using a budlist filter (b/), type filter (t/), and group message filter (g/), but no matter which filter I use I only receive messages addressed **TO my callsign**, rather than from it. For example, I've tried 'b/N0CALL-7', 'p/N0CALL', g/N0CALL-7', and t/m/N0CALL-7/10000'(replacing N0CALL with my callsign in each).

The parsed packets I do receive (for example, when I ping WXBOT for a weather update and successfully receive a message back) show my callsign-SSID as the value for the "destination" key. The "sourceCallsign" shows WXBOT, as expected for a received packet from the bot.

APRS-IS server ("APRSSERVER" in the code) is 'rotate.aprs2.net'. Port is set to 14580.

I'm using APRS-Fi to generate the messages, transmitting through my HT.

Any ideas on which filter is the appropriate one to use, or how I can re-configure the filters to get the messages I'm sending rather than those sent to me? Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question to include what the actual budlist (and other) filters you've tried. Thanks!

Comment: @webmarc updated with details. Let me know if any other info would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you try 'b/N0CALL*' to make sure you're getting *everything* that starts with your callsign?

Comment: Tried 'b/N0CALL*'. Unfortunately, it returns the same results as before.

Wondering if anyone has successfully run a query on messages sent by a callsign. Perhaps the actual APRS-IS filter spec for the servers itself is flawed?

Or maybe this is just an issue with sending messages from APRS.fi. Wish I had a better way to narrow down the issue. Thanks again for the ideas and help!